# I can't automount cifs filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, cifs, automount

I have some problem with automount.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is /etc/auto.master file.

```
#+auto.master
/mnt/nfs /etc/auto.nfs  --timeout=60 --ghost
/mnt/samba /etc/auto.sam --timeout=60 --ghost
```

And this is /etc/auto.nfs file.

```
public  -fstype=nfs4    192.168.0.1:/srv/nfs/public
```

And the last one is /etc/auto.sam file.(for cifs filesystem)

```
public --fstype=cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000 ://192.168.0.1/public
```

I succeed to mount NFS file system, but failed to mount CIFS file system. There is the folder which automount has been created but I couldn't access.

```
administrator@vm002:/mnt/smbmount$ cd public/
-bash: cd: public/: No such file or directory
```

Please give me a helping hand.

PS. Of course, I could mount manually that cifs file system. 192.168.0.1 is running NFS server and samba server, and I already opened whole port.

Comment: Can you manually mount your cifs filesystem?  Your mount options doesn't seem to have anything about authentication, did you censor that out, or how is authentication happening?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, thanks for your answering.
I gave some options for this sharing. So I wrote my /etc/auto.sam file like this.

```
public --fstype=cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000,username=billy,password=password ://192.168.0.1/public
```

But I failed so I enabled 'Turn Off password protect sharing option.' in Windows 7. 
(Control Panel > Network and sharing center > Change advanced sharing settings > Enable Turn Off password protect sharing option.)

As a result, I don't need to use usernname and password options.